# Android how can we covert emoji Unicode to ios EmojiCheatCodes and back to unicode

Tags: java, android, unicode, emoji

I have a problem while implementing emoji into android app,   app is receiving  EmojiCheatCodes from server posted by ios app,

how can i can covert from EmojiCheatCodes to android emoji unicode and back  unicode to EmojiCheatCodes?

any guide or help will be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to much around but this project by mwunsch might be of use
https://github.com/mwunsch/rumoji
otherwise you might just have to sit down and build the converter you need by yourself in which case these two pages will help

http://emoji.codes/

to help with the cheatsheet codes

http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

and this one to help with the unicode between devices
if you do go this route, make sure to post a link back here to your code so that future coders can find it easier.